# Using header(location) in PHP with jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, http-headers

Just starting to play with jQuery and jQuery mobile to be exact. I've written a login script in PHP that once the user has successfully logged in runs the following:

`header("Location: index.php");`

What I want the application to do is redirect the user to th em

When that runs though, I get the following error:

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/login.php:22) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/login.php on line 138`

The user is logged in, there isn't a problem there. When I enter the URL of the main page (index.php) and refresh it, the session variables are set etc.

I'm thinking that jQuery Mobile is posting something in the back end that's causing headers to be sent.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So what is being echoed at line 22 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/login.php?

Comment: line 22 had the following:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>

To exclude the javascript, I moved it to the bottom of the page before </body>. The error has now moved to another line, further into the body, but again, odd. It's just an opening div

<div data-role="control-group" data-type="horizontal">

Comment: That opening div __cannot__ be output before headers, it's output... headers must always be sent before output... if the script encounters any output before headers, then it will automatically send headers (and any subsequent attempt to send headers will return the warning you're seeing). One solution is to use output buffering, another is to structure your code correctly

Comment: It's great to bounce off other people. This place is great. Thanks for your help guys. It was how i structured my code. I broke it down into two sections if form is not submitted and everything that should be in there and else if the form is submitted, do action. I had the html outside of these two sections. Noob mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is JUST javascript. It can't do anything while a php script is running. It works solely in the browser.

The problem is that login.php in line 22 outputs something. You must send headers before any `echo ...` or `print()` is ever made AND before any `?>`

Comment: Either do that, or buffer the output using ob_start in the beginning and ob_end_flush in the end.