# header(location in jquery mobile not work

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I had a problem with the header ("location: index.php") if I use jquery mobile then the page is not going to index.php
is there a solution?
thank you

Comment: Use js's equivalent  `window.location = 'index.php';`

Comment: Please find following link this would help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080346/using-headerlocation-in-php-with-jquery-m][1]obile


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080346/using-headerlocation-in-php-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: Provide your php file

Answer (score 1):

put `data-ajax="false"` into the attribut of the FORM

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you *Header* call is the issue.

Look here to see if this might help you find your problem.

[PHP header() and jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403242/php-header-and-jquery-mobile)

Comment: My guess is that you are writing something before the header. Try to use PHP output buffering to fetch any output and discarding the buffer to make sure no white space or anything is sent before the header. Have you looked through you PHP and http logs to see if anything is reported there?

Comment: yeah i write something before header
if (! $ authentication-> logged_in () | |! $ authentication-> is_group ('customer')) header ("Location: login.php");

please help me ,this makes me frustrated

Comment: Without seeing all of your code it's hard to tell. My guess is that you output some text (Javascript or HTML to be printed) to the output buffer and the call the `header` function. This does not work. Instead, do an `if` check for the condition that makes you redirect using the `header` call and encapsulate all the output of text in the `else` block of that statement so that it's only printed if you are not supposed to redirect using `header`.

Comment: I use this code only for memastilkan when user want to do their transactions must be logged in if they do not log directly into the header to login.php, so I do not use the output looks like. Thank you for helping

Comment: And you don't print any information to the "screen" depending on the users current status? Or have a whitespace before `<?php` or after `?>` in any included file?

Comment: yeah my code path if not using jquery mobile and if I use the jquery mobile header will not run

Answer (score 0):

header function doesnt work if there is any output before the function is called.
it should be in the top of the page, if you cannot put it before the doctype declaration in the page, you might break the php code and enter html and redirect like this:

```
//php code
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='//URLAddrEss'">
<?php
// continue php code
```

Or you may also use javascript to redirect if you are using javascript.

Comment: I've tried it but that appears undefined, there is another solution?

Comment: if (!$authentication->logged_in() || !$authentication->is_group('customer')) header("Location: login.php");

its my code and this my sript

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>

if i dont use the script i can use header

Comment: I couldnt clearly understand the code you have typed...
Could you please type it in the correct format again?

Also tell me what you are trying to do with this?
I assume you want to redirect the person to homepage if he is not logged in... I think it will be easier and safer if you do it on the server side...

Comment: <?php

//Include the common file
require_once('common.php');

//Check if the user is logged in
if (!$authentication->logged_in() || !$authentication->is_group('customer')) header("Location: login.php");

   
?>

its's my code . Please help me
if i dont use jquery mobile the code is right